# Security in MPI implementations

Tags: security, parallel-processing, mpi, mpich

I came across a research paper andproject discussing about the implementation of encryption/decryption in the channel layer of MPICH2 called the ES-MPICH2 library http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~xqin/software/es-mpich2/index.html
According to my knowledge, MPICH2 does use the ssh layer for communication between nodes, then what would be the significance of doing this in the MPI library?

Comment: Probably would be better asked on http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Have you even read the article on their website?

Answer (score 1):

MPICH2 can use ssh for setting up the MPI environment, i.e. start the processes on the specified nodes etc., but after the setup phase actual MPI communication takes place using different mechanisms (e.g. TCP sockets, Infiniband, ...).

ES-MPICH2, which I'm completely unfamiliar with myself, then apparently encrypts the actual MPI communication.

MPI is typically used inside a single cluster, where someone eavesdropping on the MPI communications is not seen as a significant threat. In general, MPI implementations are focused more on performance than security, since that's what MPI users tend to be interested in.

Comment: The article about ES-MPICH2 (linked on the website) explains both the layered communication architecture of MPICH2, why is encryption needed (using MPI for cross-site communication), as well as what is encrypted and how.